Magento2.4.7: How to use conditional statements in email template?
This is the variable I want to use as a conditional statement.
will be 1 or 0 based on some condition

$isPlayerIncluded = 0;

inside my email template on code.

Vendor/Module/view/frontend/email/invoice_email.html

{{if isPlayerIncluded}}
<div>1</div>
{{else}}
<div>2</div>
{{/if}}

is this approach correct? and also its not working,

In Magento2.4.7 The conditional statements are not working like
{{if condition}}
{{depend condition}}

so I have to come up with a alternate solution to solve my conditional problem.
For that I use block and template file and I moved my conditional code inside that template file. and passed my data based on my requirements.
 {{block class="Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\Template" 
area ='frontend' template = 'Vendor_Module::order/email/order_confirmation3.phtml' 
subsArray=$subsArray}}

You can pass any data in that block and here is the reference blog which I followed for this solution.
https://magecomp.com/blog/magento-2-add-conditional-statement-in-email-template/?srsltid=AfmBOoplBhSrK-KIHTfC3VDuDzZbbdMigEJ9IOZ6wBzdHTFnfHL0k2Ux

In Magento 2.4.7 you can use conditional statements in email templates by leveraging the built-in templating engine, which is based on HTML combined with Knockout.js and PHP-like logic in .phtml files. However, for email templates, you can use simple if conditions using Magento's template variables and logic directly within the email.
Here’s how to use conditional statements in a Magento 2 email template:
Basic if condition:
{{if some_condition}}
  Content to display if the condition is true
{{else}}
  Content to display if the condition is false
{{/if}}

Example:
If you want to check if the customer’s first name exists, you can do something like this:
{{if var=customer.firstname}}
    Hello {{var customer.firstname}}!
{{else}}
    Hello Valued Customer!
{{/if}}


Explanation:

{{if condition}}– The if directive starts the conditional statement.
{{else}} – This is the block to be executed if the condition is false.
{{/if}} – This ends the conditional block.
Common Use Cases:
i. Checking for an order attribute:
{{if var=order.getGrandTotal() > 100}}
    Your order total is greater than 100!
{{else}}
    Your order total is less than or equal to 100.
{{/if}}

ii. Checking a specific custom variable or block:
{{if var=custom_variable}}
    We have a special offer just for you!
{{else}}
    Stay tuned for upcoming offers.
{{/if}}

Conditional Formatting:
If you want to conditionally change the appearance of certain elements (e.g., display a coupon if the total is over a certain amount), you can embed the condition within your HTML structure.

is this correct? {{if var=isPlayerIncluded==1}}

Yes correct condition.
